# Count number of rows in a matrix - Matlab

Tags: matlab, vectorization

I have been looking for quite a while now, but I still didn't find a way of counting rows of a matrix in a efficient way. There are some solutions out there, but none of them find my needs. The code above does the job, but takes too much time if your dealing with a big matrix. The output that I would like to have is the one just like the variable cont2, that is, a vector with length equal to the number of rows in A. Here is an example:

```
    A = [ 1 2 3 ; 4 3 5; 1 2 3; 1 2 3; 4 3 5; 5 2 1; 3 2 1; 3 5 1];

    [rows,~] = size(A);
    cont2 = zeros(rows,1,'single');

    for i = 1:rows
        cont = 0;
        for j = 1:rows

            if A(i,:) == A(j,:)
                cont = cont + 1;
            end

            cont2(i) = cont;
        end
    end
```

%Result:
        cont2 =

```
     3
     2
     3
     3
     2
     1
     1
     1
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about some [`bsxfun`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html)?

```
result = sum(all(bsxfun(@eq, A, permute(A, [3 2 1])), 2), 3);
```

This compares each row with each other, and sums the number of matchings to produce the desired result.

---

Equivalently, you can reduce each row to a unique integer label using [`unique`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/unique.html), and then compare those labels:

```
[~, ~, u] = unique(A, 'rows');
result = sum(bsxfun(@eq, u, u.'), 2);
```

---

Or use [`histc`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/histc.html) to count how many times each label appears:

```
[~, ~, u] = unique(A, 'rows');
c = histc(u, 1:max(u));
result = c(u);
```